# different syntax for updating multiple columns of a row

Tags: sqlite

I have to update all the columns of a row in SQLite, I know I can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
```

But this is quite painful to do, can I do something like that:

```
Update tablename then (all the columns name) and then (All the values in order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) shows that only the standard syntax is supported:
[image: UPDATE syntax diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any way you can update the table the way you are looking for:

Here are some different ways to do update query in SQL:

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php